# CSS for full-screen z-index

Tags: css

I would like to have a low-z-index `<canvas>` showing a continuous generative animation and then have a high-z-index `<div>` on top of it that has a 50% opacity white background and some text on it.

The `<div>` has lots of text so it needs to scroll vertically, but I want the `<canvas>` behind it to stay put.

How do you do this in CSS?

Comment: Consider picking up the habit of Googling before asking. This is all trivial to find out using a search. Suggested queries include `div opacity`, `div fixed position`, and `div enable vertical scroll`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming markup like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas">
<div class="top-layer">Your content</div>
```

You can achieve the top layer effect with the following styles:

```
.top-layer {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The canvas is a little trickier because you'll need to explicitly assign the height and width of this element as attributes.  You'll have to use javascript to determine the document dimensions and assign them on page load:

```
var height = document.body.clientHeight,
    width = document.body.clientWidth,
    myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
myCanvas.setAttribute('height', height);
myCanvas.setAttribute('width', width);
```

That should do it.